# Ruby On Rails 5.2 and Multiple Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three different database systems my Rails application needs to access at the same time.

We have SQL Server, an Oracle server, and of course Postgres.

I have tried to figure out how to achieve the ability to grab data from all three (multiverse, etc..).

All I get is a vague error:

> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
>   ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified in UsersController#index
>   database configuration does not specify adapter

I have `database.yml` and `database_nba.yml` which holds access to the second SQL server and cannot get it to work with two concurrent database servers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the different databases in your database.yml

```
production:
  adapter:mysql, :other_adapter, :other_adapter
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters

Check the above docs.

Comment: Here is what my database.yml file has:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  database: databasename
  encoding: unicode

So I am not sure what is missing to get rid of the error.   Any other ideas?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/amp/

Shows you how to do this and it works.   It allows me to talk to multiple databases at the same time.  Very cool!

Answer (score 1):

In order to access different databases at the same time you have to create models specific to those databases.   Once you do that, depending on the object you create it talks to the appropriate backend database.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/amp/